# Joining multiple tables in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to be able to join multiple tables in bigquery.  Joining two is pretty trivial.

```
SELECT
t1.field1 AS field1,
t2.field2 AS field2,
t1.field3 AS field3
FROM [datasetName.tableA] t1
JOIN [datasetName.tableB] t2
ON t1.somefield = t2.anotherfield
```

But what if I want to join three or more tables? Can I just do it as

```
SELECT
t1.field1 AS field1,
t2.field2 AS field2,
t1.field3 AS field3,
t3.field4 as field4
FROM [datasetName.tableA] t1
JOIN [datasetName.tableB] t2
JOIN [datasetName.tableC] t3
ON t1.somefield = t2.anotherfield AND t1.somefield=t3.yetanotherfield
```

I've tried that and it doesn't work.  I think I need to do something like

```
SELECT 
t12.field1 as field1,
t12.field2 as field2,
t3.field3 as field3,
FROM
(SELECT
t1.field1 AS field1,
t2.field2 AS field2,
t1.field3 AS field3
FROM [datasetName.tableA] t1
JOIN [datasetName.tableB] t2
ON t1.somefield = t2.anotherfield) t12
JOIN
[datasetName.tableC] t3
ON t12.field1 = t3.field1
```

But is there a simpler way to accomplish this?

Thanks,
Brad

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like below

```
SELECT
  t1.field1 AS field1,
  t2.field2 AS field2,
  t1.field3 AS field3,
  t3.field4 AS field4
FROM [datasetName.tableA] t1
JOIN [datasetName.tableB] t2 ON t1.somefield = t2.anotherfield
JOIN [datasetName.tableC] t3 ON t1.somefield = t3.yetanotherfield
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the `USING(field)` notation in Standard SQL. Which is actually just sugar for @mikhail-berlyant answer. Docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#using-clause)

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  t1.field1 AS field1,
  t2.field2 AS field2,
  t1.field3 AS field3
FROM `datasetName.tableA` t1
JOIN `datasetName.tableB` t2 USING(commonfield_AB)
JOIN `datasetName.tableC` t3 USING(commonfield_AC)
```