# Joining multiple tables in big query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I want to join multiple tables in BigQuery but the solution of [Joining multiple tables in bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864827/joining-multiple-tables-in-bigquery) did not help me to get my desired output.

My starting point is the following. I am creating 5 individual tables that are displaying each rating values possible for a specific page. See examplary output here:

[raw tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqBlo.jpg)

The table are created in the following way:

```
#standardSQL
  CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION tables_in_range(suffix STRING) AS (suffix BETWEEN (
    SELECT
      FORMAT_DATE('%y%m%d',
        DATE('2018-06-01')))
    AND (
    SELECT
      FORMAT_DATE('%y%m%d',
        DATE('2018-06-30'))));

SELECT
  h.page.pagePath AS page,
  Count(h.eventInfo.eventLabel)as five_star
FROM
  `table.ga_sessions_20*` AS t,
  t.hits AS h
WHERE
  h.eventInfo.eventAction='rating'
  AND h.eventInfo.eventLabel ='5'
  AND tables_in_range(_TABLE_SUFFIX)
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath,
    r'/xyz/')
  AND h.type='EVENT'
group by 1
```

When joining the tables as described here [Joining multiple tables in bigquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37864827/joining-multiple-tables-in-bigquery) I unfortunately do not get the expected result. 
Instead the Join is only looking at Pages that all 5 tables have in common - meaning that these are pages that have a rating in each of the five possible values ranging from 1-5. See example output below. 
[joint table results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcFWb.jpg)

```
select
five_star.page as page,
five_star.five_star as five_star,
four_star.four_star as four_star,
three_star.three_star as three_star,
two_star.two_star as two_star,
one_star.one_star as one_star
from five_star
join four_star using (page)
join three_star using (page)
join two_star using (page)
JOIN one_star using (page)
```

What I would like to achieve through my join is a table like this: 
[desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTrdg.jpg). 
The problem I see is that if a page has not received a certain rating it will not be joined in the query atm. Unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution with Union all, Cross Join or left join, so I am very grateful for any support here!

Comment: Try a left outer join. The table with all pages listed would be on the left side of the join expression. Then use IsNull to convert nulls to zeroes. Plenty of tutorials & examples online. One example is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1664266/replace-default-null-values-returned-from-left-outer-join

Comment: Thank you for forwarding this post to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in your query: you're only adding to those event pages, which had a 5-star rating. That's why [full outer join](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp) was recommended - it adds new rows to the leftmost table.

I think in your case the solution is much easier and doesn't need joins at all, because all the data is in the same table.
This one is flat and non-pivot:

```
#standardSQL
  CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION tables_in_range(suffix STRING) AS (suffix BETWEEN '20180601' AND '20180630');

SELECT
  h.page.pagePath AS page,
  h.eventInfo.eventLabel stars,
  COUNT(1) as events
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS t, t.hits AS h
WHERE
  h.eventInfo.eventAction='rating'
  AND h.eventInfo.eventLabel between '1' and '5'
  AND tables_in_range(_TABLE_SUFFIX)
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath,
    r'/xyz/')
  AND h.type='EVENT'
GROUP BY 1, 2
```

If you really need pivot-like columns it would look like this:

```
#standardSQL
  CREATE TEMPORARY FUNCTION tables_in_range(suffix STRING) AS (suffix BETWEEN '20180601' AND '20180630');

SELECT
  h.page.pagePath AS page,
  SUM( IF(h.eventInfo.eventLabel = '1', 1, 0) ) as oneStarEvents,
  SUM( IF(h.eventInfo.eventLabel = '2', 1, 0) ) as twoStarEvents,
  SUM( IF(h.eventInfo.eventLabel = '3', 1, 0) ) as threeStarEvents,
  SUM( IF(h.eventInfo.eventLabel = '4', 1, 0) ) as fourStarEvents,
  SUM( IF(h.eventInfo.eventLabel = '5', 1, 0) ) as fiveStarEvents
FROM
  `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS t, t.hits AS h
WHERE
  h.eventInfo.eventAction='rating'
  AND h.eventInfo.eventLabel between '1' and '5'
  AND tables_in_range(_TABLE_SUFFIX)
  AND REGEXP_CONTAINS(h.page.pagePath,
    r'/xyz/')
  AND h.type='EVENT'
GROUP BY 1
```

Instead of `SUM(IF(condition,1,0))` you can also `COUNT(IF(condition,1,NULL))`

hth!

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  page,
  SUM(five_star_rating) five_star_rating,
  SUM(four_star_rating) four_star_rating,
  SUM(three_star_rating) three_star_rating,
  SUM(two_star_rating) two_star_rating,
  SUM(one_star_rating) one_star_rating
FROM (
  SELECT page, 0 one_star_rating, 0 two_star_rating, 0 three_star_rating, 0 four_star_rating, five_star_rating FROM `project.dataset.table5` UNION ALL
  SELECT page, 0, 0, 0, four_star_rating, 0 FROM `project.dataset.table4` UNION ALL
  SELECT page, 0, 0, three_star_rating, 0, 0 FROM `project.dataset.table3` UNION ALL
  SELECT page, 0, two_star_rating, 0, 0, 0 FROM `project.dataset.table2` UNION ALL
  SELECT page, one_star_rating, 0, 0, 0, 0 FROM `project.dataset.table1` 
)
GROUP BY page
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table5` AS (
  SELECT 'A' page, 1 five_star_rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 1 
), `project.dataset.table4` AS (
  SELECT 'C' page, 1 four_star_rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F', 1 
), `project.dataset.table3` AS (
  SELECT 'F' page, 1 three_star_rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'G', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'H', 1 
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 'H' page, 1 two_star_rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J', 1 
), `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 'J' page, 1 one_star_rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'K', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L', 1 
)
SELECT 
  page,
  SUM(five_star_rating) five_star_rating,
  SUM(four_star_rating) four_star_rating,
  SUM(three_star_rating) three_star_rating,
  SUM(two_star_rating) two_star_rating,
  SUM(one_star_rating) one_star_rating
FROM (
  SELECT page, 0 one_star_rating, 0 two_star_rating, 0 three_star_rating, 0 four_star_rating, five_star_rating FROM `project.dataset.table5` UNION ALL
  SELECT page, 0, 0, 0, four_star_rating, 0 FROM `project.dataset.table4` UNION ALL
  SELECT page, 0, 0, three_star_rating, 0, 0 FROM `project.dataset.table3` UNION ALL
  SELECT page, 0, two_star_rating, 0, 0, 0 FROM `project.dataset.table2` UNION ALL
  SELECT page, one_star_rating, 0, 0, 0, 0 FROM `project.dataset.table1` 
)
GROUP BY page
```

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution with Union all, Cross Join or left join ...

Another option is to use FULL JOIN  as in example below

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  COALESCE(five_star.page, four_star.page, three_star.page, two_star.page, one_star.page) AS page,
  IFNULL(five_star.five_star_rating, 0) AS five_star,
  IFNULL(four_star.four_star_rating, 0) AS four_star,
  IFNULL(three_star.three_star_rating, 0) AS three_star,
  IFNULL(two_star.two_star_rating, 0) AS two_star,
  IFNULL(one_star.one_star_rating, 0) AS one_star
FROM `project.dataset.table5` five_star
FULL JOIN `project.dataset.table4` four_star USING (page)
FULL JOIN `project.dataset.table3` three_star USING (page)
FULL JOIN `project.dataset.table2` two_star USING (page)
FULL JOIN `project.dataset.table1` one_star USING (page)
```

You can test, play with above using dummy data from your question  as below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table5` AS (
  SELECT 'A' page, 1 five_star_rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'B', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'C', 1 
), `project.dataset.table4` AS (
  SELECT 'C' page, 1 four_star_rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'D', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'F', 1 
), `project.dataset.table3` AS (
  SELECT 'F' page, 1 three_star_rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'G', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'H', 1 
), `project.dataset.table2` AS (
  SELECT 'H' page, 1 two_star_rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'I', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'J', 1 
), `project.dataset.table1` AS (
  SELECT 'J' page, 1 one_star_rating UNION ALL
  SELECT 'K', 1 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'L', 1 
)
SELECT
  COALESCE(five_star.page, four_star.page, three_star.page, two_star.page, one_star.page) AS page,
  IFNULL(five_star.five_star_rating, 0) AS five_star,
  IFNULL(four_star.four_star_rating, 0) AS four_star,
  IFNULL(three_star.three_star_rating, 0) AS three_star,
  IFNULL(two_star.two_star_rating, 0) AS two_star,
  IFNULL(one_star.one_star_rating, 0) AS one_star
FROM `project.dataset.table5` five_star
FULL JOIN `project.dataset.table4` four_star USING (page)
FULL JOIN `project.dataset.table3` three_star USING (page)
FULL JOIN `project.dataset.table2` two_star USING (page)
FULL JOIN `project.dataset.table1` one_star USING (page)
```

result as expected:

```
Row page    five_star   four_star   three_star  two_star    one_star     
1   A       1           0           0           0           1    
2   B       1           0           0           0           1    
3   C       1           1           0           0           1    
4   D       0           1           0           0           0    
5   F       0           1           1           0           0    
6   G       0           0           1           0           0    
7   H       0           0           1           1           0    
8   I       0           0           0           1           0    
9   J       0           0           0           1           0
```

Comment: Dear Mikhail, thank you very much both replies. I tried the solution with the FULL JOIN just now and it works perfectly! I will try your example with the subselect / UNION ALL as well but as of now this is exactly the table I was looking for. Thank you!